# Why are user.home and user.name question marks in Jenkins agent build?

Tags: java, jenkins

A fellow team have a gradle build running in a Jenkins Agent in Kubernetes using `container("...)` where for some reason the `user.home` and `user.name` properties are set to question marks, causing library code trying to use files in the user home directory to get malformed file names.

```
user.home: ?
user.language: en
user.name: ?
```

What set of circumstances could result in this?    Current user id not found in `/etc/passwd`?  Values overriden by Jenkins?  Permission problem in image?